# Display result after each loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

In the code below, a url variable is increasing by 1 every time in a while loop. When `$i` is equal to 1000, the loop will end and `$i` will be displayed (from 1 all the way to 1000).

How do I display the value of `$i` after every loop, rather than waiting to the end?

```
$i = 1;
while($file = file_get_contents('http://example.com?id='.$i)) {
    if($i !== 1000) {
            echo $i;
    }else{
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Put the echo outside of the if statement?!

Comment: @Rizier123 The issue is still happening... I have to wait for $i to equal 1000 before $i is displayed

Answer (score 2):

You will need to flush message after each iteration. That way your browser will receive part of the information even if your request/response is still pending.

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);

$i = 1;
while($file = file_get_contents('http://example.com?id='.$i) && $i < 1000)
{
    echo $i;
    $i++;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: this is correct one . but little bit betterment `<?php
$i = 1;
while($file = file_get_contents('http://example.com?id='.$i))
{
    ob_flush();
 flush();
    if($i == 1000){
        break;
    }
 echo $i;
 $i++;

}
ob_end_flush();`

Comment: This was a good suggestion, but it still does not display `$i` after each loop.

Comment: It should work if you are using updated php version. I have tested it. Btw, I have made couple code tweaks

Comment: I tried your updated version but it hasn't change anything

Comment: Uste this site to test it, http://phptester.net/.

<?php 

ob_implicit_flush(true);

$i = 1;
while($i < 1000)
{
    echo $i;
 $i++;
 ob_flush();
 flush();
 sleep(1);
}

ob_end_flush();

Comment: That site has disabled file_get_contents. Can you reproduce my problem on http://www.runphponline.com/?

Comment: It is working ok on that site too, a little bit slower, but it is working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122016/discussion-between-the-codesee-and-asmir-zahirovic).

Answer (score 0):

Move `echo $i;` outside of the `if()` statement:

```
$i = 1;
while($file = file_get_contents('http://example.com?id='.$i)) {
if($i !== 1000) {
    //    echo $i;
}else{
    break;
}
    echo $i;
    $i++;
}
```

This scenario is surely better suited for `for()` loop instead of `while()`...

Comment: The issue is still happening... I have to wait for `$i` to equal 1000 before `$i` is displayed

Answer (score 0):

PHP happen on the server. To see each value for $i immediately you would need to make the server:

> 1. do it's thing -> display that thing -> reload.

you can reload with `header()` but that is limited to 20 reloads (I think) unless you use `header("Refresh:0");`

I would make it display by making a stacking condition.

```
   if(isset($diplay)){//2+ times through
      $display = $display . $i . "<br>";
   }else{//first time through
      $diplay = $i."<br>";
   }
```

then put that inside your condition

```
if($i !== 1000) {
   if(isset($diplay)){
      $display = $display . $i . "<br>";
   }else{
      $diplay = $i."<br>";
   }
}else{
    break;
}
```

echo $display

```
echo $display;
```

Then increment your variable

```
$i++;
```

then refresh page and pass the variable at the same time.

```
header("Refresh:0; url=page.php?i=$i");
```

then you'll have to add a condition at the beginning that gets $i or assign it if not found.

```
if(isset($_GET['i'])){//meaning if it's found in the url like so ?i=$i
  $i = $_GET['i'];
}else{//first time through
  $i = 1;
}
```

///////////////////putting it all together////////////////////////

```
if(isset($_GET['i'])){
  $i = $_GET['i'];
}else{
  $i = 1;
}

while($file = file_get_contents('http://example.com?id='.$i)) {
  if($i !== 1000) {
    if(isset($diplay)){
      $display = $display . $i . "<br>";
    }else{
      $diplay = $i."<br>";
    }
  }else{
     break;
  }
  echo $display;
  $i++;
  header("Refresh:0; url=page.php?i=$i");
}
```